# Require one argument only in Apache Commons CLI?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm just wondering is there any way in the Apache Commons CLI library to specify that exactly one argument must be provided?

E.g. I have 2 command line arguments, but one (no more or no less) must be provided? I want either the ip or msisdn, but not neither and not both:

```
OptionBuilder.hasArg(true);
OptionBuilder.withDescription("Bla bla");
OptionBuilder.isRequired(false);
commandLineOptions.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("ip"));

OptionBuilder.hasArg(true);
OptionBuilder.withDescription("Bla bla");
OptionBuilder.isRequired(false);
commandLineOptions.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("msisdn"));
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you want a required [`OptionGroup`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionGroup.html) containing the two mutually-exclusive `Option` values. Add that option group to `commandLineOptions`.

(This is only a guess based on the documentation. I've never actually used the project myself...)